Why is my voltage divider circuit not accurate?
I have created a voltage divider circuit for reducing a 28V input voltage to under 3V output for a red LED. The resistors used are with 5.1k and 1.5k ohms. In theory these values should provide a 6.36V output but when I measure with multimeter the voltage across the diode it says 1.8V.
How is that possible? Does it have something to do with a load effect of the LED or its something else.


Welcome! Please draw a schematic of what you have and how it’s connected. It sounds like the Vf of your LED is clamping the voltage, but the devil is in the details.

Is it a raw machine 28V or a regulated clean one?

it is a power supply for testing

You have calculated the divider for a no- load condition. The calculated voltage will be correct as long as nothing that draws current is connected to it. When you connect a load the additional current drawn will add to the current through the top resistor which will then drop more voltage.
This can be easily calculated for a resistive load, just recalculate with the bottom resistor and load in parallel, but for a non-linear device such as a diode it will be a bit trickier. An LED has a forward voltage that depends on its construction and current, this voltage will be different for different colors. If your LED has a forward  voltage of 1.8 V at the current that’s going through it then that’s the voltage you’ll measure across it and the divider won’t make much difference. What you should probably do is calculate a single resistor to limit the LED current to within its ratings by dividing the source voltage minus the forward voltage by the desired current.
So if you wanted 10 mA through the LED you would need a dropping resistor of
$$
R_{drop}=\frac{28V-1.8V}{10mA}=2620\Omega
$$
You stated in a comment that the LED dims when you lower the supply voltage. This is normal, the lower voltage will reduce the current. Suppose you lowered it to 20 V, this would give you
$$
I_{LED} = \frac{20V-1.8V}{2620\Omega}=6.95 mA
$$
and the LED would be dimmer because an LED's brightness is mostly dependent on the current through it.
If you want the LED brightness to be constant over a range of supply voltages you need to either use a constant current source or a voltage regulator to keep the voltage to the LED and resistor constant.
Let's say you have a supply voltage range of 15V to 28 V, you could use a 9 V regulator to supply the LED through a 720 Ω resistor, and the LED current and brightness would remain constant at ~10 mA.
Here's an example of a constant current source compared to a simple resistor. Over a supply voltage range of 20 V to 30 V the CCS keeps the LED current within 350 uA while with the resistor it varies around 3.8 mA, more than 10 times as much as the CCS.


LED - non-return valve analogy
LEDs are diodes (that emit light). Diodes are electrical non-return valves. (Incidentally, in old radio terminology what Americans called “tubes” the English called “valves”. This is due to their rectification properties and that they behave like a certain type of valve in a water system.)

Figure 1. The diode check-valve analogy.
If you look at the check-valve in the figure above, it should be clear that the spring normally keeps the ball in position and prevents back-flow. When “forward-biased” the ball shut-off can be moved against the spring but it will take some initial pressure to move the ball. This results in a pressure drop across the valve: the pressure downstream will be less than the inlet pressure.
In a similar manner the PN junction causes a voltage drop. For silicon it is about 0.7 V. Since there is a PN junction in the base-emitter of your transistor you can expect a 0.7 V drop across it when forward biased.
Pushing the analogy a little further, we can also see that further pressure drop will occur due to the constriction of the valve. The more water we push through the valve the more the pressure will drop. This will be added to the initial pressure drop required to open the valve in the first place. The resultant pressure drop graph will look remarkably like one of the I vs V curves below.

Figure 2.
Note that as the current increases the voltage across the diode will increase but not in proportion to the current. In your case, changing the resistor values will have limited affect over quite a wide range of resistor values.
All images mine, from LEDnique.


Does it have something to do with a load effect of the LED

Yes. This is the equivalent circuit of your voltage divider:

As you can see, just 2mA at the LED would cause the loss of a few Volts at the resistor.
$$(6,36-1,8)/1159 \approx 3.9 mA$$
$$(28-1,8)/3.9 mA \approx 6.7 k\Omega$$
\$6.8 k\Omega\$ is a close 5% standard value for a series resistor at 28V input, which will dissipate around 100 mW.

FYI, LEDs, depending on their color and type, have a characteristic forward voltage when they are conducting. For a red LED, this forward voltage typically ranges from 1.8V to 2.2V. This is the voltage required for the LED to start conducting and emitting light. Since you're measuring 1.8V across the LED, it seems this is the forward voltage at which it operates.
It's due to the loading effect on the voltage divider. The voltage dividers work perfectly when the load is negligible or has a very high impedance compared to the resistors in the divider. An LED acts like a non-linear load, however. It doesn't behave like a high-resistance load, but instead it conducts and clamps the voltage to its forward voltage once it's forward biased.
In your case the divider is designed to output 6.36V unloaded.
Once the LED is connected as a load, it pulls the voltage down to its forward voltage, in this case 1.8V.
Essentially, the LED is regulating the voltage across it by drawing current and clamping the voltage down to its forward voltage.

How does the LED pull down the voltage to its forward one? Does it have something else in it that does this? Also, can he LED reduce any voltage or it needs to be to a specific value?

LEDs are a type of diode, and diodes have a threshold voltage called the forward voltage. This is the minimum voltage required for the diode to conduct current. For LEDs, the forward voltage depends on the material and color of the LED.
When you apply a voltage across the LED that is higher than this forward voltage, the LED starts conducting current, and the voltage across the LED is "clamped" at this forward voltage.

When your LED become 'ON' , I mean when Voltage across it is above the threshold voltage , the Impedance of your led become really small , so as you have LED in parallel with a 1.5k , the lowest impedance win that's why the voltage at the output of your circuit (6.36V) drop

The LED has a forward voltage of about 1.8V so it does not matter if the LED is fed from  a voltage divider or just a series resistor, there will be 1.8V over the LED.

But when I reduce the power supply voltage the led is dimmed. If the voltage divider does not make any difference what stops me from connecting the led directly in the input voltage?

"But when I reduce the power supply voltage the led is dimmed" because the voltage divider is equivalent to a series resistor and you are reducing the voltage across the resistor, which reduces the current. If you connect it directly to the voltage source and it is capable of source enough current (it probably is) the LED will be destroyed @MaksimKasnedelchev

Then do i need to use a voltage divider or i can just use one resistor in series?

@MaksimKasnedelchev As explained, without any resistors the LED will explode. But whether you have a divider or simple series resistor, in both cases the LED will dim when you lower the power supply voltage because less current goes through LED.

...I would add @MaksimKasnedelchev that using the divider makes no sense; it's just a way of dissipating more power. If your power supply is stable, use a series resistor. Otherwise, you need more complex circuits to maintain the brightness constant (for example like this one)

@Rmano Sometimes it may make sense. Sometimes it might not. We cannot know what is the optimal solution in this case, but often LEDs are dimly lit with residual charge in some bulk capacitor, and extra resistor over the LED will make sure the capacitor discharges fully instead of being clamped to 1.8V LED voltage with microamps keeping the LED lit.

LEDs can typically handle a fair bit of voltage. They generally care about current, not voltage. So the correct way to supply a LED is not through a voltage divider but a plain series resistor. In your schematic most of the current goes through the LED and nearly none across the 1.5k resistor which just sits there taking up board space. And so the voltage you measure is probably pretty close to the specified LED forward voltage.
Example:
Lets say we have 2 Vfwd and the LED is rated for 20mA. But it will glow like the sun at that current, we really just need 5mA. And so:
(28 - 2) / 5*10^-3 = 5.2k.
Okay but 5.1k is standard E series. Conclusion: smack on a 5k1 resistor in series, done. Or in your case, probably just desolder the useless 1.5k resistor.
